# Excel VBA command Workbook_open not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to get workbook_open to display a message when I open a workbook.

Based on past feedback I have placed the code in the "This workbook" tab. Works in one file and doesn't in another. What should I look for?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   If Weekday(Now) = vbThursday Then
    Msg = "Today is Thursday. MAke sure that you "
    Msg = Msg & "submit the TPS report."
    MsgBox Msg, vbInformation
   End If
 End Sub
```

The message is not displayed

Comment: Any chance that in your Excel macros are disabled (but files in certain folders are macros trusted/allowed)? Check the Trust Center in the Excel options, and tell us your macro security options.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it worked. This means it's not an issue with how it is written but other factors.

Double check your spreadsheet is saved as a file type that allows macros, such as `.xlsm` or `.xlsb`.

When you open the file, check it there's a yellow ribbon saying "Enable Content". Trust the file, then each time it's opened after that it should run.

Comment: Thanks, all MAcros are enabled and file is saved as an XLSM file. Could some other Macro setting be doing this?

Comment: @user9020604 can you confirm that Macros are enabled when it the file is opened (not enabled after it was opened)?

Comment: This is useful How would I check tthat?